# Is it possible to override the base OS from base Docker file?

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

We have a requirement to use CentOS in all Docker containers for maintenance reasons.

One of our dependency Docker file has [java:8](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/2dd0496901a9c01c78895d0e6618b36c08f78bde/openjdk-8-jre/Dockerfile) as its base image.

`FROM java:8
......`

This base image uses debian based linux as its base OS.

Is there a way to override the debian with centos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to override the debian with centos?

Not really. One workaround would be to re-specify those images:

- [openjdk](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/2dd0496901a9c01c78895d0e6618b36c08f78bde/openjdk-8-jre/Dockerfile)
- [buildpack-deps:jessie](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/Dockerfile)
- [buildpack-deps/jessie-scm](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/scm/Dockerfile)
- [buildpack-deps/jessie-curl](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/curl/Dockerfile) which starts `FROM debian:jessie`

So you need to rewrite those Dockerfile, starting from the curl one, this time witrh a [`FROM centos7`](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/)